# MDX cross join result

Tags: ssas, mdx, analysisservices

I'm getting a result from my cross join thay I can't wrap my heads around, see my first MDX query that gives me a result **as expected.** (SQL Server Analysis Services 2012)

[image: Succesfull query]

Alright, now I want to do the same thing, only I want to target a specific date, let's take "2020-05-05". This is what happens:

[image: Empty..]

I get an empty result, why don't I see the the results from the first query (limited to the rows with 2020-05-05)? I really do not understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the SSAS Cube was only partially processed, doing a full process of everything seems to have solved the problem.

Altough, I would still appricaite an explanation on why the second query failed? The first query shows quite clear that the cube, at that state, contained information on 2020-05-05?